# Microsoft dynamics AX - how to create legal entity using rest api

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am using the AX 2012 R2 version.

I have read some forums and blogs related to Microsoft Dynamics AX, I haven't found any help, but I know someone maybe has already done it.

So I am trying to figure out how to create a legal entity in Microsoft Dynamics AX(2012 R2) using **REST** API. Are there any REST APIs available that can allow me to put my data into AX to create a legal entity?

Why do I want to do this?
As we are building a CRM tool where a user can set up his details using forms and that will be submitted to our system. Our system will trigger the API that can create all the necessary things that we need to do in AX manually. In short, I am trying to automate the AX process from our system.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate any manual process in AX and then [expose it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/walkthrough-exposing-an-x-class-as-a-data-contract) as a SOAP-based [custom service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/using-custom-services). To call the service from the Internet, you would have to [publish it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/consuming-microsoft-dynamics-ax-services-from-an-external-client) through IIS.

If you needed a JSON-based service, you could create a Logic App with the "[When HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint)" trigger and use your exposed AX service from there via [HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) action.

Comment: thanks a lot :), correct me if I wrong, I need to create these services in AX, right? Just curious, are there any built-in services that can be directly used?

Comment: AX 2012 has many built-in Document Services https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/standard-document-services such as CustCustomerService, VendVendTableService, HcmWorkerImportService, etc. that can be just configured and enabled. However, normally such standard services need to be customized (i.e. AX development would be required) to satisfy specific requirements.

Comment: thank you very much, I am accepting your answer. :)